# Microsoft word, save to Web Page Filtered, images names issue

Tags: ms-word

When saving a Microsoft Word document to a `Web Page, Filtered`, it creates and htm file and put the images into a new created folder. The extracted images took the names `image001.png`, `image002.png`, `image003.png`, `image004.png`,... and they are referenced in the htm file by these names.
My question is: In Microsoft Word, is there any image property to put a name there and when saving to Web Page, the images will be saved with that name? If I set name **installer-fig1**, the extracted image name should be `installer-fig1.png` and referenced in the html code by it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Word has no facility for that. You could, of course, rename the images and edit the HTML file once it's been created.

Comment: Thanks @macropod. It seems I will write a script to automate this.